# Is reformatting links on old questions worthy of approving the edit?

Tags: discussion, editing, formatting

I found an edit in my edit review queue, that just reformats the link to use a different style of coding. Should I approve this edit or reject and fix the grammar errors myself? Or should I just leave it since it is an old answer and hardware changes really quickly?

[Here is the edit](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/13350)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a good edit. It doesn't improve the post. It doesn't provide better formatting. It hasn't "Fixed the URL", as the summary says.

This Edit should be Rejected as "This edit fails to improve the post."